# issue with indexOf in simple card game javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, indexof

I'm trying to make a really simple javascript card game but am having a small issue that I can't seem to figure out. Basically the following code is supposed to build up a deck of cards... the issue is commented in the code below, I have a bit of script that is supposed to randomly assign the suits and values to the cards and push them into the deck array. The indexOf method in the if statement is supposed to check if a random card has already been pushed to the playing deck to prevent duplicate cards but I still seem to be getting duplicates. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction on this:

```
//selecting the cards types for the deck.
var cards = []; 
var numberedCards = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var faceCards = ["Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"];
var suit = ["of hearts", "of diamonds", "of clubs", "of spades"];

while (!(cardOptions == "a" || cardOptions == "b" || cardOptions == "c")) {
    var cardOptions = prompt("What cards do you need? \nType 'a', 'b', 'c'.\na. All cards \nb. Face cards only \nc. Numbered cards only");
    switch (cardOptions) {
        case "a":
            cards = numberedCards.concat(faceCards);
            break;
        case "b":
            cards = faceCards; 
            break;
        case "c":
            cards = numberedCards;
            break;
        default:
            alert("You have to choose one an option");
    }
    console.log("You have chosen cards " + cards + ". Let's add the suits to make your deck.");
}

//the following code is supposed to:
///Randomly assign suits to the cards and push the cards into array playingDeck.  
//"indexOf" is suppose to tell me if the randomCard is already in the playingDeck, but 
//I'm still getting duplicate cards.

var playingDeck = [];

do {
    var randomNumberCard = cards[Math.floor(Math.random()*cards.length)];
    var randomSuitCard = suit[Math.floor(Math.random()*suit.length)];
    var randomCard = [[randomNumberCard],[randomSuitCard]];

    if(playingDeck.indexOf(randomCard) === -1) {
        playingDeck.push(randomCard);
        continue;
    }
    else {
        continue;
    }
} while (playingDeck.length <= cards.length*suit.length - 1);

console.log(playingDeck);
console.log("ok, you now have " + playingDeck.length + " to play with.");
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Comment: if indexOf is used to find complex object, you should provide your implementation. see discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=2&sort=newest

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure I understand what you mean by my implementation, this is for an intro to javascript class, this is the only code I have to show so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.indexOf()` checks arrays for strings - in this case you are trying to match an array object (not a string).

You can either use jQuery's `$.inArray()` method, or iterate through your card deck like this:

```
var found = false;
for ( var card in playingDeck ) {
   if (card[0] == randomCard[0] && card[1] == randomCard[1] ) {
    found == true;
   }
}

if ( !found ) playingDeck.push(randomCard);
```

Comment: Saying that `.indexOf()` checks arrays for strings is not very correct. Of course you can use it for this but actually you can also scan normal strings for some containing stuff. e.g `var foo = "hello world";
alert(foo.indexOf("wo")); ` what would output 6